# R - Change row values of a column by row values from another column

Tags: r, rows

I have a data frame such as:

```
X1 X2
A Type1
A Type2
N Type1
A Type3
N Type2
N Type2
```

X1 and X2 are factors and not characters.

I would like to have the following data frame:

```
X1 X2
A Type1
A Type2
N NR
A Type3
N NR
N NR
```

As you can see, when X1 is equal to "N", I want X2 to be equal to "NR". I have try to use ifelse and other functions but it does not work and return "FALSE".

Here is a code that I have tried:

```
df<-within(df, X2[X1=="N"] <- 'NR')
```

Comment: Most likely, the issue is that you are working with factor variables rather than character variables. You can check this using `str(df)` where df is the name of you data.frame. To read in character variables, use `as.is=TRUE` in `read.csv` or `read.table`. You can convert to character using `df$X1 <- as.character(df$X1)` for example. With character variables (in particular with X2 as a character vector), `df[df$X1 == "N", "X2"] <- "NR"` will accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table` to assign in place

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[X1=="N", X2 := "NR"]
```